# IronPython | Redirect Output To Textbox

Tags: python, c#, output, ironpython

Ok so, let's say I am executing a script with IronPython in C#:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
string Script = textBox1.Text();
engine.Execute(Script);
```

Now let's say the script was:

`print("Hello")`

Output in VS Console: Hello
What I am trying to achieve here is to redirect that output to a TextBox in C#. I have tried the following method which didn't work:

```
class TextBoxWriter : TextWriter
{
    private RichTextBox _textBox;

    public TextBoxWriter(RichTextBox textbox)
    {
        _textBox = textbox;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        _textBox.AppendText(value.ToString());
    }

    public override System.Text.Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

Form1_Load:

```
engine.Runtime.IO.RedirectToConsole();
TextWriter _writer = TextWriter.Synchronized(new TextBoxWriter(textBox1));
Console.SetOut(_writer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just that in my code and its functional for me.

```
engine.Runtime.IO.RedirectToConsole();    
Console.SetOut(new TextBoxWriter(textBox1));
```